# Safari Text Input and Number Input Size

Tags: html, css, safari

So, I haven't seen any questions that seem to pertain to the issue I'm having. I have a bunch of CSS and HTML, but the problem spots are my text and number inputs. My CSS and styling works on google chrome on windows, but has inherent issues on any safari or apple-based browser.

The `selectAnswer` dropdown and the `numberAnswers` inputs don't change size on safari, and it makes them kind of hard to read, as they default to much smaller than the rest of my text.

Is there something I need to do that's specific to Safari in order to make the dropdown and number inputs larger, or is there something simpler that I'm just overlooking?

HTML:

```
<p class="question">Questions</p>
<br/>        

<div class="selectAnswer">

    <select style="font-size:16pt">
        <option value="novalue" id="novalue">Please select an option.</option>
        <option value="option1" id="option1">option1</option>
        <option value="option2" id="option2">option2</option>
        <option value="option3" id="option3">option3</option>
        <option value="option4" id="option4">option4</option>
        <option value="option5" id="option5">option5</option>
        <option value="option6" id="option6">option6</option>
    </select>
</div> 
<br/>


<div class="numberAnswers">

    <label for="num1">please input the first number</label><br/>
    <input type="number" style="font-size:16pt;height:22px;" name="num1" id="qNum1">

    <br/>
    <br/>

    <label for="num2">please input the second number</label><br/>
    <input type="number" style="font-size:16pt;height:22px;" name="num2" id="qNum2">
    <br/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
label{
    margin-left: 30px;
    display: block;
    color: #0B2643;
    font-size:22px;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.5s, font-size 0.5s;
    transition: color 0.5s, font-size 0.5s;
}

label:hover{
    color:#7A0000;
    font-size:26px;
}

select{
    line-height:18px;
}

.selectAnswer{
    display:block;
    color:#0B2643;
}

.numberAnswers{
    display:block;
    color:#0B2643;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing this at the top of your CSS sheet:

```
* {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: That seems to have worked! Now I'm finding that the text exactly fills the box, and that's a touch hard to look at. Is there any way I can create some extra space IN the box, or make the box larger, but not the text therein?

Comment: Also, this actually seems to have removed some other elements that should be showing up. I had some radio buttons that are now not appearing, it seems. Is there some way I can get those back, or does that directly contradict the solution you've given me?

Comment: What the * does is make every element on your website have the `-webkit-appearance: none;` style, so if it has effected some elements, then remove that and simply add `-webkit-appearance: none;` to each element that you isn't following your styles in Safari. So within the CSS for "selectAnswer" add `-webkit-appearance: none;` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/xgebi/dy1wduw1/

You need to add to select

```
 select {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   font-size: 24px;
}
```

Comment: I have some radio buttons outside of this code snippet, and `-webkit-appearance: none;` seems to make those disappear. Is there any way I could use this but exempt my radio buttons from being hidden away?

Comment: Did you use * { } or select { }? I added to that fiddle a radio button and it didn't disappear. '*' affects all elements on the webpage. 'select' only all selects.

Comment: Oh, my apologies, I didn't see that your response was different from the others. Let me give that a shot.